# Is it possible to automatically tail Kubernetes pod logs after it restarts

Tags: kubernetes

I'm aware of the usual way to "tail --follow" logs of a Kubernetes service:

```
kubectl logs -f -lapp=service-name --all-containers=true
```

But every time I push a change to this service the `kubectl` dies when the pods get killed and I have to run it again.

Example error message:

> Received interrupt, cleaning up...
>   rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: b48a1ad3c0080680465c79903d03748a026becf397bc780921674b2f0d7078ffReceived interrupt, cleaning up...
>
> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: 6258e31702ea678eacec5ad0df15b5620b5609cd5e4822f2e4991fd26c9906b6
>   $

What I wonder is if there is a way to tell Kubernetes to keep looking for new pods which match the `-lapp=service-name` tag and tail them. A bit similar to `tail --follow=name --retry`

I suppose I can run the command in a simple shell loop but was wondering if there is something smarter that can use `Kubernetes`, one which will avoid lots of errors while the new pods get deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about instead of using [`stern`](https://github.com/wercker/stern)?

Basically, you can use the same structure of the command, just replace `kubectl logs -f -lapp=service-name --all-containers=true` into `stern -l app=service-name`

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. I'm curious to see if there is some "built-in" way to achieve this.

Comment: So far I haven't got another response and this solution works great. It's even available to install via Homebrew.